# Initializing Array of Class Object in list

Tags: c++, initializer-list

`Car` is a template class, and its constructor is defined as follows:

```
template <class carObject>
explicit Car( const carObject & notFound, int size = 101 );
Car( const carObject & rhs )
```

In my header file (`h`), I have:

```
class Storage{
public:
    Storage();
    Car <char*> myCars[12];
};
```

In my CPP file (`.cpp`), I'm trying to initialize `myCars` array using initializing list as follow:

```
Storage::Storage()
: myCars("notFound", 20)
{ //my other stuff}
```

but I keep getting the error message:

```
error: invalid initializer for array member Car:myCars("notFound", 20)
```

Any help?

Comment: Where does `Storage::Storage` come from?

Comment: @TonyTheLion it's inherited from Garage

Comment: @TonyTheLion `Storage::Storage` is the class that has `Car <char*> mycars[12]` declared in

Comment: @Andy the point is that it isn't obvious from your question.  You need to add all relevant information to your question.

Comment: @TonyTheLion edited. Tell me if this is clear enough?

Comment: The obvious error is that your `Storage` constructor is declared as `Storage()` and then defined as `Storage(char* name, int capacity)`

Comment: @TonyTheLion You're right, but that's not the issue here. That was a typo.

Comment: @Andy Don't do this. Make your question correct. There's no excuse for being lazy there. Just copy your actual code. Make it SSCCE. See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

Your array need 12 initializers like

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad007f275d9825f2)</kbd>**

```
template <typename T> struct Car {
    template <class carObject> explicit Car(const carObject &notFound, int size = 101) {}
};

struct Storage {
    Storage()
            : myCars{
                  Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 },
                  Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 },
                  Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 },
                  Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 }, Car<char *>{ "notFound", 20 },
              } {}
    Car<char *> myCars[12];
};

int main(){}
```

Of course you can leave out some initializers if the element type is default-constructible. But the structure of the initializer would need to match this structure